# Make Flask Marshmallow NestedSchema work wtth my API route

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm making an APi using Flask, SQLAlchemy, and Marshmallow.

The model is defined and the database is populated with data and when the view is hit. I get all the fields JSON content from `NonProfitSchema`.

```
class NonprofitSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Nonprofit

        # To specialize fields something like so
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'ein', 'ico', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'group', 'subsection', 'affiliation', 'classification', 'ruling',
 'deductability', 'foundation', 'activity', 'organization', 'status', 'tax_period', 'asset_cd','income_cd', 'filing_req_cd', 'pf_filing_req_cd',
 'acct_pd', 'asset_amt', 'income_amt', 'revenue_amt', 'ntee', 'sort_name', 'activity_full')
```

I was trying to make a new Schema from this and return only a subset of the data with so below

```
class AddressSchema(NonProfitSchema):

    from marshmallow import fields 
    address = fields.Nested(NonprofitSchema(only=("street", "city", "state", "zipcode",)))
```

I had routes in my view.py set up as so:

```
@api_blueprint.route("/api/orgs/id/<int:id>/", methods=["GET"]) def get_org_by_id(id):
    org = Nonprofit.query.get(id)
    return npschema.jsonify(org)

@api_blueprint.route("/api/orgs/address/<int:id>/", methods=["GET"]) def get_org_by_id_address(id):
    org = Nonprofit.query.get(id)
    return addyschema.jsonify(org)
```

However, when accessing them in a browser. They both return the exact same thing which is the entire database model of `NonprofitSchema`

I'm supposing it's not possible to do subsets of data with the Schema, right?

Comment: You should specify which marshmallow version you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should update the answer that I went with. While I and user 
*c8999c 3f964f64* basically thought of the same way and that will indeed sort of work. In my case, "jsonify" on the object wouldnt work as in his example  I built a separate function as there is no `items` attribute. So with a filter made that uses get attribute as so:

```
def jsonfilter(obj, attrlist):

    resp = {}
    for attr in attrlist:
        resp[attr] = getattr(obj,attr)
    return resp
```

Then modifying the function as so to use it:

```
@api_blueprint.route("/api/orgs/id/<int:id>/address", methods=["GET"])
def get_org_address_by_id(id):
    org = Nonprofit.query.get(id)
    only_these_fields = ["id", "ein", "name", "street", "city", "state", "zipcode"]
    return jsonify(jsonfilter(org, only_these_fields))
```

I was able to make it work.

Alternatively and a much simpler way after reviewing the Flask and Flask-Marshmallow documentation is to simply instantiate a new class object of the model with fields passed in.

```
@api_blueprint.route("/api/orgs/id/<int:id>/address", methods=["GET"])
def get_org_address_by_id(id):
    org = Nonprofit.query.get(id)
    only_these_fields = ["id", "ein", "name", "street", "city", "state", "zipcode"]
    addyschema = NonprofitSchema(fields=only_these_fields)
    return addyschema.jsonify(org)
```

I opted against this method because I prefer to only need one separate class object and calling a filter method feels better.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can plug this logic right into the jsonify step

```
org = Nonprofit.query.get(id)
only_these_fields = ["street", "city", "state", "zipcode"]
return addyschema.jsonify({key: value for key, value in org.items() if key in only_these_fields}
```

Comment: Yea, I was thinking this might be the only way to go myself.  Im waiting for any other methods but if not II'll just accept this as best and proceed.

Comment: I know that feel. I hate when packages like Marshmallow make things more complicated than easier. There really should be a better way, but I can't see why your solution doesnt work either. Maybe wait for a few days for a Marshmallow expert to show up

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the whole picture but I find it strange to nest the parent schema in the child.

What about this instead (untested)?

```
class AddressSchema(NonProfitSchema):

    class Meta:
        fields = ("street", "city", "state", "zipcode",)
```